# Finding a set of vectors with minimal variation among its pairwise distances

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry, normed-spaces

Given an $n$-dimensional vector space, I want to find a set of $m$ vectors $(V_i)_{i = 1 .. m}$ such that the pairwise euclidean distances between each vector in the set have minimal sample variance. (Measures of variation other than the sample variance would also be fine. I am just looking for distances that are "as similar as possible" to each other.)

For a given size $m$, how can I find such a set?

Here's my thoughts so far:

- For what concerns the edge case of a set with variance zero in the distribution of pairwise distances (i.e. all vectors in the set have the same pairwise distance), I am fairly convinced that such a set is findable only if $m \le n+1$. For example: in 1 dimension, a set of points with equal pairwise distances can have at most 2 points; in 2 dimensions, a set of points with equal pairwise distances can have at most 3 points (a triangle).
- However, if I want a set with $m > n+1$ elements, I don't really know what's a good intuition to tackle this problem.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are asking. If the vectors are not random, then it does not make sense to talk about "probability distribution" of distances, since nothing is random (unless you mean the empirical probability distribution). In this latter case, you are correct that the answer is to choose the vertices of an $n$-dimensional simplex, with $n \leq m$.

Comment: I see, thanks for the comment. I am interested in the variation between the values of the pairwise distances, so I guess I should refer to the "sample variance" of such a population of vectors. I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: Just to clarify: what I'm interested in is to find some colors (which can be seen as vectors in a 3D space) whose pairwise distances are roughly the same. I hope this gives a better idea of my problem.

Comment: Yes, sample variance will do.